# How to have bash interpret part of the command as MySQL commands

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell

I want to write a bash script that would include a few MySQL statements.

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -u root --password=passwd
CREATE DATABASE test
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* TO 'testuser'@'localhost' \
IDENTIFIED BY 'passwd';
```

When I run db.sh I get the following error: `bash CREATE:command not found.`

I tried the following with no luck either:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat << EOF | mysql -u root --password=passwd
CREATE DATABASE test;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* TO 'testuser'@'localhost' \
IDENTIFIED BY 'passwd';
EOF
```

Is there a way to let bash know the command followed by `mysql -u root --password=passwd` are MySQL commands instead of bash commands?

Comment: Your second example works fine for me, are you getting an error or something?

Answer (score 0):

Put the commands into a file them pipe it into mysql. I.e.

```
mysql -u root --password=passwd < file_with_commands.sql
```

Or, using EOF:

```
mysql -u root --password=passwd << EOF
<comands>...
```

Edit: further to your comment, try this (all on one line):

```
mysql -u root --password=passwd -e "CREATE DATABASE test; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* TO 'testuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'passwd';"
```

Comment: Thanks! My problem is I have to specify the entire command in a single string that will be passed on to some other program. If I run "mysql -u root --passowrd=passwd <<EOF '\n' CREATE DATABASE test; '\n' EOF" I get the same error.

Comment: Thanks dwjv. I get the following error now: Error 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax: check the manual that corresponds to your  MySQL server version fir the right syntax to use near passwd in line 1.

Comment: The `<<EOF` syntax is called a "here document". The marker can be any word, not just "EOF".

Comment: Not sure what to say, the commands work for me. You must be doing something different. I just tried mysql-e "CREATE ..." on my local machine and it worked.